# Hide an <a> tag in Grease Monkey

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

```html
<div id="hub-clock-time-entry" class="hub-clock-time-entry">
    <h3>YOU'RE CURRENTLY NOT CLOCKED IN</h3>
    <table class="hub-clock-time-buckets">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <button id="btnMeClockIn" class="large positive fill" type="button">
                    CLOCK IN NOW
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td class="small" style="text-align: center;">
                <a id="lnkClockInMulligan" href="javascript:void(0);"
                   data-hasqtip="true">Forgot to clock in earlier?</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I am trying to have Grease Monkey find the "Forgot to clock in earlier?" link, and disable it (hide or delete).  Hiding the entire DIV was easy, however, I am having trouble hiding the link based on its id.

Comment: Just `$("#lnkClockInMulligan").remove();` should do it, so if that is not working please show us the relevant portion of the code that you use on GreaseMonkey so we can cheack what is wrong

Comment: Use the code found in the duplicate question.  The function call would be: `waitForKeyElements ("#lnkClockInMulligan", hideNode);`.